# Let $B$ be a subset of a space $X$. Prove that the following statements are equivalent

Tags: general-topology

> **Question**: Let $B$ be a subset of a space $X$. Prove that the following statements are equivlent.$^1$
>
> (a) $B$ is nowhere dense.
>
> (b) $X\setminus \bar{B}$ is dense in $X$.
>
> (c) $X\setminus \overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}=\emptyset$.
>
> (d) $B\subseteq \overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}$.

**Notation:**

- $\operatorname{int}A$ is an [*interior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)) of $A$.
- $A'$ is a [*derived set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)) of $A$.

**My attempt**

- (a)$\Rightarrow$(b): If $B$ is nowhere dense, then $\operatorname{int}\bar{B}=\operatorname{int}(X\setminus (X\setminus \bar{B}))=\emptyset$. Thus $X\setminus \bar{B}$ is dense in $X$.
- (b)$\Rightarrow$(c): If $X\setminus \bar{B}$ is dense in $X$, then $\overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}=X$, so $X\setminus \overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}=X\setminus X=\emptyset$.
- (c)$\Rightarrow$(d): If $X\setminus \overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}=\emptyset$, then $\overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}=X$, so $B\subseteq X = \overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}$.
- (d)$\Rightarrow$(a): Suppose that $B\subseteq \overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}$. Then $\bar{B}\subseteq\overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}$ and so $\operatorname{int}\bar{B}\subseteq\operatorname{int}\overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}$. Suppose that $\operatorname{int}\bar{B}\ne\emptyset$. Then there exists $x\in \operatorname{int}\bar{B}$, and so $x\in\operatorname{int}\overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}$. Since $x\in\operatorname{int}\overline{(X\setminus \bar{B})}$, $x\in (X\setminus \bar{B})$ or $x\in(X\setminus \bar{B})'$. If $x\in (X\setminus \bar{B})$, then $x\in\operatorname{int}\bar{B}\subseteq\bar{B}$ and $x\in (X\setminus \bar{B})$, which is a contradiction. If $x\in(X\setminus \bar{B})'$, then $\operatorname{int} \bar{B}$ must contain an element of $X\setminus \bar{B}$, but $\operatorname{int}\bar{B}\cap (X\setminus \bar{B})=\emptyset$, a contradiction. Thus, $\operatorname{int}\bar{B}=\emptyset$ and so $B$ is nowhere dense.

In my attempt, the proof that (d) implies (a) is much more longer than other three, so I feel strange. Are there any proofs to justify (d)$\Rightarrow$(a) shorter and easier than mine?

---

$^1$ Fred H. Croom(2003). *Principles of Topology*. Cengage Learning. page 108.

Comment: In $(a)\to (b)$ it would be better style to write $\emptyset =Int (\bar B)=Int (X$ \  $(X  $ \  $  \bar B)), $ leading with the initial hypothesis $\emptyset =Int (\bar B)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without fancy formulas.

(a)$\implies$(b) Let $U$ be an open set such that $U\cap(X\setminus \overline{B})=\emptyset$. Then $U\subseteq\overline{B}$; since $\overline{B}$ has empty interior, this implies $U=\emptyset$. So every nonempty open set intersects $X\setminus\overline{B}$.

(b)$\implies$(c) Since $\overline{X\setminus\overline{B}}=X$, the statement is obvious.

(c)$\implies$(d) Since $\overline{X\setminus\overline{B}}=X$, the statement is obvious.

(d)$\implies$(a) Let $U$ be a nonempty open set contained in $\overline{B}$. Then $U\cap B\ne\emptyset$, so we can take $x\in U\cap B$. By assumption, $x\in\overline{X\setminus\overline{B}}$, so there is $y\in X\setminus\overline{B}$ with $y\in U$, because $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Therefore $y\notin\overline{B}$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

For $(d)\Rightarrow(a)$, $\bar{B}\subseteq\overline{X\setminus\bar{B}}=X\setminus\text{int}\bar{B}=(X\setminus\bar{B})\cup (\bar{B}\setminus\text{int}\bar{B})\Rightarrow \bar{B}\subseteq\bar{B}\setminus\text{int}\bar{B}$, which means $\text{int}\bar{B}=\emptyset$.  (Note that the trivial $\overline{X\setminus A}=X\setminus\text{int}A$ is invoked.)

Comment: I don't think that $\overline{X\setminus A}=X\setminus \operatorname{int}A$ is trivial.

Comment: But it frequently occurs as an exercise in topology textbooks(at least in those ones I have read)...We may prove it simply in one sentence :$x\not\in\text{int}A\Leftrightarrow \text{Any open neighborhood of }x\text{ interacts with } X\setminus A \Leftrightarrow x\in\overline{X\setminus A}$.